# update value from different xml node using XSLT if in SAP CPI

Tags: xml, if-statement, xslt, sap-cpi

I have some trouble for update value using if on XSLT from other reference element.

- D_3035 field value SU should be available and populated.
- D_3055 field value should be 92 from 9.

But all other BY/CA/ST on D*3035 was impact and changed all value 92 on D*_3055

Would you be able to provide XSLT code review and let us know?

1. Source XML

   ```
    <G_SG2>
         <S_NAD>
            <D_3035>CA</D_3035>
            <C_C082>
               <D_3039>MYCARRIER</D_3039>
               <D_3055>92</D_3055>
            </C_C082>
         </S_NAD>
      </G_SG2>
      <G_SG2>
         <S_NAD>
            <D_3035>BY</D_3035>
            <C_C082>
               <D_3039>0000152055</D_3039>
               <D_3055>9</D_3055>
            </C_C082>
         </S_NAD>
      </G_SG2>
      <G_SG2>
         <S_NAD>
            <D_3035>ST</D_3035>
            <C_C082>
               <D_3039>0000152055</D_3039>
               <D_3055>9</D_3055>
            </C_C082>
         </S_NAD>
      </G_SG2>
      <G_SG2>
         <S_NAD>
            <D_3035>SU</D_3035>
            <C_C082>
               <D_3039>3000</D_3039>
               <D_3055>9</D_3055>
            </C_C082>
         </S_NAD>
      </G_SG2>
   ```
2. XSLT

   ```
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:variable name="varD_3035" select="//D_3035"/>
   <xsl:variable name="varD_3055" select="//D_3055"/>

   <xsl:template match="D_3055">
   <D_3055>
           <xsl:value-of select= "if( $varD_3035 = 'SU' ) then '92'  else $varD_3055 "/>
   </D_3055>
   </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
   ```
3. incorrect xml

   - all 92 was populated on D_3035

   ```
      <G_SG2>
         <S_NAD>
            <D_3035>CA</D_3035>
            <C_C082>
               <D_3039>MYCARRIER</D_3039>
               <D_3055>92</D_3055>
            </C_C082>
         </S_NAD>
      </G_SG2>
      <G_SG2>
         <S_NAD>
            <D_3035>BY</D_3035>
            <C_C082>
               <D_3039>0000152055</D_3039>
               <D_3055>92</D_3055>
            </C_C082>
         </S_NAD>
      </G_SG2>
      <G_SG2>
         <S_NAD>
            <D_3035>ST</D_3035>
            <C_C082>
               <D_3039>0000152055</D_3039>
               <D_3055>92</D_3055>
            </C_C082>
         </S_NAD>
      </G_SG2>
      <G_SG2>
         <S_NAD>
            <D_3035>SU</D_3035>
            <C_C082>
               <D_3039>3000</D_3039>
               <D_3055>92</D_3055>
            </C_C082>
         </S_NAD>
      </G_SG2>
   ```

I run XSLT several times but it is same.

I am expecting XML as below:

```
   <G_SG2>
      <S_NAD>
         <D_3035>CA</D_3035>
         <C_C082>
            <D_3039>MYCARRIER</D_3039>
            <D_3055>9</D_3055>
         </C_C082>
      </S_NAD>
   </G_SG2>
   <G_SG2>
      <S_NAD>
         <D_3035>BY</D_3035>
         <C_C082>
            <D_3039>0000152055</D_3039>
            <D_3055>9</D_3055>
         </C_C082>
      </S_NAD>
   </G_SG2>
   <G_SG2>
      <S_NAD>
         <D_3035>ST</D_3035>
         <C_C082>
            <D_3039>0000152055</D_3039>
            <D_3055>9</D_3055>
         </C_C082>
      </S_NAD>
   </G_SG2>
   <G_SG2>
      <S_NAD>
         <D_3035>SU</D_3035>
         <C_C082>
            <D_3039>3000</D_3039>
            <D_3055>92</D_3055>
         </C_C082>
      </S_NAD>
   </G_SG2>
```

Comment: Some notes: your stylesheet uses `version="1.0"` but `if (expression) then expression else expression` is only available in XPath 2 and therefore XSLT 2 and later. Thus, if you don't get a syntax error for that that `if () then .. else ..` expression it appears you are using an XSLT 2 or 3 processor. Therefore I would suggest to start using `version="2.0"` in your XSLT. As for your samples, can you both make them minimal but complete to allow us to easily reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems

```
 <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
     <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="S_NAD[D_3035 = 'SU']//D_3055">
  <xsl:copy>92</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

might express your requirement (although the formulation is not clear to me).

And I don't know why, in the wanted result, you have

```
 <S_NAD>
     <D_3035>CA</D_3035>
     <C_C082>
        <D_3039>MYCARRIER</D_3039>
        <D_3055>9</D_3055>
     </C_C082>
  </S_NAD>
```

as the input has

```
  <S_NAD>
     <D_3035>CA</D_3035>
     <C_C082>
        <D_3039>MYCARRIER</D_3039>
        <D_3055>92</D_3055>
     </C_C082>
  </S_NAD>
```